# Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of null in karma testing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am writing karma/jasmine test case for the click event, but I am getting null for button. Please suggest me. Thanks in Advance.

```
  it('should', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'clickMethod');
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#view-rec');
    console.log(button); --> button is null I am getting
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.clickMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

component::

```
  clickMethod() {
      this.msg.node.setVal(false);
      this.myBtn = "Hello";
  }
```

Html::

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="dropdown">
  <button mat-menu-item>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item id="view-rec"(click)='clickMethod()'>   
  </button> 
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: There is no conditional rendering, It is inside mat-menu dropdown

Comment: Can you try this:

let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#view-rec'));

Comment: Did you call detectChanges before accessing DOM?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to open the menu 1st, and then you'll get access to the `mat-menu-item` which you want to click.

For example:

```
<button id="menu-open-icon" mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> 
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu"> 
  <button mat-menu-item id="view-rec"(click)='clickMethod()'>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

try:

```
it('should', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'clickMethod').and.callThrough();
    let menuIcon = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#menu-open-icon')
    menuIcon.click();
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#view-rec');
    console.log(button); --> this should not be null now
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.clickMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: @Vivek Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @Vivek, I am able to get button details with id="menu-open-icon". but I am unable to get the button with id="view-rec", because of  mat-menu is loading dynamically from other component. please suggest me, how to get the dynamic loading button details.

Comment: @YYY : sure, can u please add more HTML code to help me understand. Also , any comments for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678832/how-to-create-stubs-for-karma-jasmine-testing-in-angular/64680431#64680431 ?