# How to create stubs for Karma/jasmine testing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, stub

Any one can explain how to create Stubs for service mocking for Angular Karma testing. Please provide any complete example or link.
After creating the stub, how to write the test cases using stub data. Please explain.

`Spy` Vs `stub` which one is best practice. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find about creating `stubs` and `spies` [in this article of mine](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49).

Coming to your 2nd question, choosing stub and `spy` is more about the implementation scenarios. One can used over other based on situation. For ex:

1. Use `Stub` to replace actual service. In this way, you can reuse the same `stub` at other `components.spec` as well. Hence it creates reusable code.
2. Now, there are times when your services returns value differently depending on code (lets say, it throws `error` in some `http` call and you have handled that in your code). To test such conditions, you can simple create a `spy` and override the `stub` response. Check my [article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) where I have done the same.
3. If its a quick overriding of values, use `spy`

I hope it helped.